# How can I divide the figure into the fields using SilverLight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

Can someone help me solve the question: How can I divide the figure into the fields, so depending on which area will be  mouse click it will be carried out a specific event?

```
    private void LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (!isDragging)
        {
            //creating of my  user control element
            NodePicture node = new NodePicture();
            node.Width = 100;
            node.Height = 100;

            //use cursor position as the center of the figure
            Point point = e.GetPosition(this);
            node.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, point.Y - node.Height / 2);
            node.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, point.X - node.Width / 2);
            node.MouseLeftButtonDown += controlReletionshipsLine;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(node);
        }
    }

    private void controlReletionshipsLine(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //creating parant element of node
        ParentNode parentNode = new ParentNode();

        //creating connected element of the node
        ConnectedNode connectedNode = new ConnectedNode();

        //creating node element
        NodePicture node = (NodePicture)sender;

        //getting the relative position of the element
        Point point = e.GetPosition(this);
```

Comment: More details required.  What do you mean by figure??

Comment: For example a circle, I need to divide it into some parts.@ Myles J

Comment: is it smth similar to html map ?

Comment: Maybe something like that, but when you click on it should be called an event.@baalazamon

Comment: Circle? OK are we talking about an elipse shape object or image?

Comment: about an elipse shape object.@Myles J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either divide the object mathematically, using the mouse position "relative to the object" to decide where you clicked, or you can overlay a number of polygons, each with the colour alpha-channel set to 1% (so they can be hit-tested, but are not visible).

As you simply want to see which quarter of the circle you clicked in, call [GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979880%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on the LeftMouseButtonDown event args, passing the control itself as the parameter. This will give you back a [Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980089%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) object with the position relative to the top left corner of the control.

Then it is just a matter of seeing which quarter it is in:

```
private void ControlX_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the relative position of the element
    Point point = e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement);

    if (point.X > control.Width/2)
    {
        if (point.Y > control.Height/2)
        {
            // You are in the bottom right quarter
        }
        else
        {
            // You are in the top right quarter
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (point.Y > control.Height/2)
        {
            // You are in the bottom left quarter
        }
        else
        {
            // You are in the top left quarter
        }
    }
}
```

In the sample code you sent me (in `controlReletionshipsLine`) you have:

```
// getting the relative position of the element
Point point = e.GetPosition(this);
```

It should have been:

```
// getting the relative position of the element
Point point = e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement);
```

Comment: I have a figure of circle with 4 buttons: bottom, top, left and right inside the circle. And I need to generate an event when I click some part(bottom, top, left and right inside the circle) of it.@HiTech Magic

Comment: if it is only quarters, you just need to check whether the relative mouse position is above or below half the width/height of the control.  I will update my answer now.

Comment: It doesn't work, because point.X is not a relative position it is the position of mouse cursor, so in this case :(if (point.Y > control.Height/2)) - it will be always true @HiTech Magic

Comment: Please read answer carefully: "call GetPosition on the LeftMouseButtonDown event args, **passing the control itself as the parameter.**". If you pass the control to GetPosition the coordinates will be relative to the control. *If you provide your code it will be easier to show you and avoid misinterpretations*.

Comment: Can we connect via mail, because I can't add  the main part of my code, because of not perfect validation? @ HiTech Magic

Comment: In the specific example you sent me you are using the container instead of the target to get the relative position :)

Comment: Please note it should be spelt Relationships, not Reletionships, but I have left your spelling as-is.